# Is merge faster than insert query when running over thousands of rows of data to get them into Snowflake?

Tags: sql, merge, insert, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I used to work with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO hub_location
            (
                        location_hkey,
                        load_dt,
                        record_src,
                        location_type,
                        location_value
            )
SELECT md5(concat_ws('', 'BLOCK', Object_construct(*):BLOCK)) AS block_hkey,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
       'ONA',
       'BLOCK',
       object_construct(*):BLOCK
FROM   temp_table_name
WHERE  block_hkey IS NOT NULL
AND    block_hkey NOT IN
       (
              SELECT location_hkey
              FROM   hub_location)
AND    EXISTS
       (
              SELECT object_construct(*):BLOCK
              FROM   temp_table_name)
UNION ALL
SELECT md5(concat_ws('', 'FACILITY', object_construct(*):FACILITY_ID)) AS facility_hkey,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
       'ONA',
       'FACILITY',
       object_construct(*):FACILITY_ID
FROM   temp_table_name
WHERE  facility_hkey IS NOT NULL
AND    facility_hkey NOT IN
       (
              SELECT location_hkey
              FROM   hub_location)
AND    EXISTS
       (
              SELECT object_construct(*):FACILITY_ID
              FROM   temp_table_name);
```

The purpose of doing it this way is that sometimes we are receiving data having `BLOCK` and/or `FACILITY_ID` so we need to check them both.

I changed the above query into a merge as follows:

```
MERGE INTO HUB_LOCATION HL
USING (select object_construct(*):BLOCK AS BLOCK, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):FACILITY_ID AS FACILITY_ID FROM TEMP_TABLE_NAME) ST
ON MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY
    AND MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.BLOCK IS NOT NULL AND MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)) NOT IN (SELECT LOCATION_HKEY FROM HUB_LOCATION) THEN
    INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_TYPE, LOCATION_VALUE)
    VALUES (MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.FACILITY_ID IS NOT NULL AND MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)) NOT IN (SELECT LOCATION_HKEY FROM HUB_LOCATION) THEN
    INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_TYPE, LOCATION_VALUE)
    VALUES (MD5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.FACILITY_ID)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID);
```

The table below shows a comparison between the 2 queries in milliseconds over only 2 rows, as we don't have too much data for now. but in the future, there will thousands of data passing through the data pipeline into Snowflake.

[image]

When starting having thousands of rows coming into the pipeline, will the merge statement keep the same behavior of executing in less time?

**EDIT: UPDATED MERGE QUERY**

```
MERGE INTO HUB_LOCATION HL 
USING 
(SELECT DISTINCT 'BLOCK' AS LOCATION_TYPE, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK AS LOCATION_VALUE FROM TEMP_TABLE_NAME 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT 'FACILITY' AS LOCATION_TYPE, object_construct(*):FACILITY_ID AS LOCATION_VALUE FROM TEMP_TABLE_NAME) 
ST 
ON MD5(CONCAT_WS('', ST.LOCATION_TYPE, ST.LOCATION_VALUE)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY 
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.LOCATION_VALUE IS NOT NULL THEN 
    INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_TYPE, LOCATION_VALUE) 
    VALUES (MD5(CONCAT_WS('', ST.LOCATION_TYPE, ST.LOCATION_VALUE)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', ST.LOCATION_TYPE, ST.LOCATION_VALUE) ;
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the difference in the execution profile to evaluate why the MERGE is faster.  It is not likely related to the MERGE as much as it is the execution plan of the INSERT with all of those EXISTS statements.  Without seeing the execution profile, though, it is hard to say for sure what is happening.

Comment: Does exists clause increase the querying time ? @MikeWalton.

Comment: Not necessarily, but in this case it might.  A JOIN would likely be faster, but again, without a profile to see what Snowflake is executing, it is hard to say.